# Passar função X como parâmetro para função Y, mas só definir parametro de X dentro de Y

Tags: python, python-3.x, funções

Alguém sabe como fazer o código abaixo funcionar?

Ou alguma alternativa que funcione, mas que siga o princípio.

```
def f_numbers(number='no'):
    if number == 'no':
        return 'Você não definiu um número'
    else:
        return 'Seu número: '+number


def func2(func):
    set_number = 2
    print(func(set_number))


def func1():
    func2(f_numbers())


func1()
```

Meu código original é diferente, mas fiz essa pequena simulação para que seja de fácil compreensão.

**Atualização:**
Lembrando que só posso definir o parâmetro de `f_numbers` dentro da função `func2`, pois esse valor é definido de acordo com um loop `for` que fica dentro de `func2`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[TL;DR](https://repl.it/@sidonduarte/send-function-to-function)

Se eu entendi corretamente, vc cometeu 2 erros, o primeiro é quando voce envia a função `f_numbers` para `func2`, ao invés de enviar o objeto vc esta enviando a execução e o segundo é na propria funcao f_numbers quando vc concatena a sua mensagem com o numeros enviado, faltou fazer o typecast, tente com o codigo abaixo:

```
def f_numbers(number='no'):
    if number == 'no':
        return 'Você não definiu um número'
    else:
        return 'Seu número: '+str(number)

def func2(func):
    set_number = 2
    print(func(set_number))

def func1():
    func2(f_numbers)

func1()
```

**Saida:**

```
Seu número: 2
```

[Veja funcionando no repl.it](https://repl.it/@sidonduarte/send-function-to-function)

Comment: Algo tão simples de se resolver rs. Eu achava que em python, uma função enviada por parâmetro só era interpretada como função se tivesse sido passada com os parênteses também. Realmente essa linguagem é incrível, muito simples e prática. Obridado @Sidon

Answer (score 1):

Uma forma de fazer isso é a seguinte:

```py
def f_numbers(number=True):
    if number:
        return 'Seu número: '+ f'{number}'
    else:
        return 'Você não definiu um número'


def func2(f_numbers):
    number = <Aqui você digita um número ou None caso queira um valor nulo>
    print(f_numbers(number))


def func1():
    func2(f_number)


func1()
```

O output é o seguinte:

Se você digitar um número:

```
$ python3 functions.py
Seu número: 2
```

Se você deixar `None`:

```
$ python3 functions.py
Você não definiu um número
```

Comment: Obrigado pela contribuição. Mas nesse caso essa alternativa não me serve, pois o valor da função `f_numbers ` só pode ser definido dentro da função `func2`

Comment: @Suel, entendi. Bom, se caso ninguém consiga responder sua questão amanha eu tento. Até mais :)

Comment: @Suel, é desse jeito que você queria?

Comment: Sim, exatamente. A sua resposta juntamente com a do amigo @Sidon funciona como eu gostaria. Muito obrigado !